# Git compare two branches in relation to a third

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-diff

Working with github/gitlab, using feature branches in many cases pull requests go out of date while waiting for a review and need to be rebased on top of the new target branch (master) after a while.

This will sometimes create conflicts that need to be solved.

After a rebase I would like to compare the old and the new branch in relation to the target branch, to verify no errors have been made while solving the conflicts. Meaning I would like to verify which lines are going to change after merging the new version of the PR.

So basically I would like to diff the result of `git diff branch origin/master` and `git diff origin/branch origin/master` - what changed in the diff output on the PR view of github/gitlab between the old and new versions.

Is there a command to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't `git diff branch origin/branch` do the diff you want, given that you have rebased `branch`?

Comment: No, that will contain the diff that was merged into branch from master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the form of `git-diff` that [takes multiple commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt82308203ltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203):

> `git diff <commit> <commit>…​ <commit>`

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt82308203ltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203):

> This form is to view the results of a merge commit. The first listed  must be the merge itself; the remaining two or more commits should be its parents.

In your case, you want to compare the merge commit between the rebased `branch` and `origin/master` with the merge commit between the old `origin/branch` and `origin/master`; the comparison then becomes:

```sh
git diff branch origin/master origin/branch
```

where `branch` is the "merge commit" and `origin/master` and `origin/branch` are its "parents".

In case of a conflict, Git is going to produce the following diff:

```
- line in origin/master (the first "parent" commit)
- line in origin/branch (the second "parent" commit)
+ line in branch (the merge commit)
```